# Import coordinates from a text file to pin on google map android gps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am doing my graduation thesis and I have to do an Android application which shows my location on Google Maps (something I have done), and when I come close to some places inside the university will pop up some informations for the buildings (something I might do it with proximity alert). The point is that I want to import the places which they will be showed on map as a pin from a text file.

Is that possible (I have done it but static from inside the code)? I am working on Eclipse and if it will be useful I can copy/paste the code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
    marker.setBounds((int) (-marker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),-marker.getIntrinsicHeight(),(int) (marker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),0);        
    mapController=mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    InterestingLocations funPlaces= new InterestingLocations(marker);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(funPlaces);

    GeoPoint pt=funPlaces.getCenterPt();
    int latSpan=funPlaces.getLatSpanE6();
    int lonSpan=funPlaces.getLonSpanE6();
    Log.v("Overlays", "Lat span is " + latSpan);
    Log.v("Overlays", "Lon span is " + lonSpan);

    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(pt);
    mc.zoomToSpan((int) (latSpan*1.5), (int)(lonSpan*1.5));


    whereAmI= new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(whereAmI);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

public class InterestingLocations extends ItemizedOverlay{
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> locations = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private GeoPoint center=null;

    public InterestingLocations(Drawable marker){
        super(marker);

        GeoPoint disneyMagicKingdom = new GeoPoint((int)(37.97897823618044*1000000) ,(int)(23.6723855137825*1000000));
        GeoPoint disneySevenLagon= new GeoPoint((int)(37.98013047446126*1000000) ,(int)(13.6715030670166*1000000));
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(disneyMagicKingdom,"Magic Kingdom","Magic Kingdom"));
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(disneySevenLagon,"Seven Lagon","Seven Lagon"));

        populate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. keep the text file in asset folder of resources. read location from it and place an overlay(pin for that location) on the map while loading it. if you need a tutorial to get started with google maps, then [here](http://www.androidhive.info/category/gps/) is a good one.

Comment: The link doesn't work i'll wait to read the article.Above is my code take a look if you want.

Comment: It was working when i posted. may be the the sites server is down. try after sometime. 

I think your code looks fine. just keep the place details in a text file in the asset folder of "res". read and parse for each location and place an itemized overlay just like you are doing it now.

Comment: How can i make clear where the first coordinate starts and ends inside the text file?

Comment: keep some delimiter like ";" or something. while parsing use that to split the coordinates.

Comment: I can't make it work.If you have any free time and want to help this is my mail tailer35@hotmail.com.All the other work but i cant read from the asset folder.